# Генерация токена в Oracle

Tags: oracle, token

Как получить токен в Oracle? Как правильно это сделать (только подробно).

Comment: А что за токен?

Comment: https://habrahabr.ru/company/dataart/blog/311376/

Comment: Это я знаю, но как это относится к базам данных? Это ведь серверное дело. Мб, вам подойдет генерация GUID -- через SYS_GUID

Comment: Объясню подробнее, есть апи функции, вот эти: https://gist.github.com/Maxim1234567/512d92af078bc1b2f092cff4c39b86a2. Как можно заметить, в каждой апи происходит авторизация. Как мне сказали, жто очень сильно тормозит их работу и посоветовали использовать токен. Проблема в том, что я понятия не имею, как его использовать и что для этого нужно и т.д. Порылся, возможно сбился с верного пути, осталось только просить помощи у тех кто знает, поэтому пишу сюда

Comment: Юзер заходит по логину/паролю, генерируется его личный токен, который сохраняется в базе (и скорее всего прописано когда токен протухает, например он будет жить 24 часа), когда юзер отправляет запрос с токеном, мы в базе его находим и считаем что авторизация пройдена. Как-то так... GUID'ы могут подойти в качестве токенов: `select SYS_GUID() FROM DUAL;` -> `206F4FD2E3EE48DD829C6C5D03AF726B`

Comment: А как потом применять этот токен в место авторизации?

Comment: Серверу ведь отправляют логин/пароль, и тот авторизует, ведь так? Получается, что для авторизации по токену нужно будет в коде написать проверку.

Comment: Не совсем понял, в коде приложения или в коде api-функций?

Comment: `в коде api-функций` там где у вас сервер и доступ к базе

Comment: Так, я вообще запутался, смотрите, если ссылку, которая генерируется библиотекой ретрофит при доступе к БД на сервер, поместить в адресную строку браузера, то она запросит логин и пароль от самой БД, но только один раз, и в дальнейшем, если обновлять страницу или написать там другую ссылку от этой же БД, то он не будет опять запрашивать логин и пароль. Если вы правильно меня поняли, то можете написать эту проверку или что там требуется. Извините за мою глупость)